# MVC3 windows authentication, Custom Roles Provider and custom AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, roleprovider, authorize-attribute

I'm implementing a custom AuthorizeAttribute in my mvc3 application. I have a Custom Roles Provider with my GetRolesForUser. I add cacheRolesInCookie in a web.config

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRolesProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieProtection="All">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="CustomRolesProvider" type="Prisma.Security.CustomRolesProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

In my AuthorizeAttribute I check roles for user with command filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole.

Each call to this method called GetRolesForUser and its implementation.
I can use the data in cookies?

Comment: Could you check if the `HttpContext.User` is of type `RolePrincipal`?